# jQuery equivalent for attaching a handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

What is the equivalent code in jQuery for the below JavaScript function?

```
function attachSomeHandler(in) {
    for(var i = 0; i < in.length; i++) {
        if(in[i].type == 'submit') 
            in[i].attachEvent("onclick", someFunc);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the argument `in` is an array of DOM elements and you already have that array and you want to reproduce the exact same function `attachSomeHandler()`, you could do this using jQuery:

```
function attachSomeHandler(in) {
    $(in).filter('[type="submit"]').click(someFunc);
}
```

If you want to back up to a higher level in your code, you can create a single jQuery selector that would get the original array of DOM elements that was already filtered to only have ones with the appropriate type.

Comment: Pardon me if im wrong..i think the user just wants to bind the click function for later use..not to click it

Comment: @ubercooluk - See the [jQuery doc for `.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).  When you pass a function to it like this `.click(someFunc)`, it binds an event handler for click.  It doesn't actually click it.

Comment: Basically I want to invoke someFunc(say to disable submit button) when it is clicked.

Comment: all my code is in javascript which is not working on other browsers except IE. I'm planning to change the whole code to Jquery for make it browser independent. Can some one suggest me the steps how to accomplish this as I'm new to Jquery. Thank you very much for all the help so far.

Comment: @amrinAra - We're not going to teach you jQuery here in SO.  I'd suggest you start reading up about how jQuery works [here](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works) and [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials). If you have another specific question about how to convert a piece of regular JS to jQuery, you can ask a new question about that piece of code.  StackOverflow is not meant to be a discussion tool where you ask multiple questions in the same thread.

Comment: Thank you very much for the jquery links!!

Comment: function attachSomeHandler(in) { 
    $(in).filter('[type="submit"]').click(someFunc); 
} 
The above resolved my problem. Thanks a billion..